# trouble downloading an internet image using standard c sockets

Tags: c, image, sockets, download, tcp

Beginner, writing my first socket based code in C, trying to download an image file from the internet, I get:

## Output:

```
IP addresses for 'brokenthorn.com':

  IPv4: 64.90.36.159

Received 1380
Received 1380
Received 240
Received 0
```

Then the image file is not really an image file, it starts with:

## Downloaded content:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 30 Jan 2018 09:47:14 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Mon, 17 May 2010 00:55:30 GMT
ETag: "3c6b-486bfae6b8480"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 15467
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/png
```

Then lots of unknown content, but the file size is much smaller than it would be with the real image. **What am I doing wrong?**

## Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int send_all(int fd, char *buf)
{
   int total_sent = 0;
   int bytes_left = strlen(buf);

   int bytes_sent;
   while (total_sent < bytes_left) {
    bytes_sent = send(fd, buf + total_sent, bytes_left, 0);
    if (bytes_sent == -1) {
        break;
    }

    total_sent += bytes_sent;
    bytes_left -= bytes_sent;
   }

   return bytes_sent == -1 ? -1 : 0;
}

int recv_all_to_file(FILE *file, int sockfd)
{
    char buf[3000];
    int total_bytes_recd = 0;

    while (1) { 
        ssize_t bytes_recd = recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof buf - total_bytes_recd, 0);
        printf("\nReceived %d", bytes_recd);
        if (bytes_recd <= 0) {
            break;
        }

        total_bytes_recd += bytes_recd;
        fwrite(buf, bytes_recd, 1, file);
    }
}

int main(int argc, int *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);    // make sure the struct is empty
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;            // don't care IPv4 or IPv6   
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;        // TCP stream sockets

    // get ready to connect
    int status = getaddrinfo("brokenthorn.com", "80", &hints, &res);
    printf("IP addresses for 'brokenthorn.com':\n\n");

    for (p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        void *addr;
        char *ipver;

        // get the pointer to the real address
        // different fields in IPv4 vs IPv6
        if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) {
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
            ipver = "IPv4";
        } else {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
            ipver = "IPv6";
        }

        // convert IP to a string and print it
        inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
        printf("  %s: %s\n", ipver, ipstr);
    }

    // get a socket
    int sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
    printf("Could not create socket");
   }

    // connect
    if (connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen)) {
    puts("connect error");
      return 1;
   }

    char *msg = "GET http://brokenthorn.com/Resources/site/5.png HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: brokenthorn.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\nKeep-Alive: 300\r\n";
    if (send_all(sockfd, msg) == -1) {
        puts("send error");
      return 1;
    }

    // download
    remove("5.txt");
    FILE *file = fopen("5.txt", "ab");
    if (recv_all_to_file(file, sockfd) == -1) {
        puts("download and save to file error");
      return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    close(sockfd);
    fclose(file);
    freeaddrinfo(res);

    return 0;
}
```

## Fix for small file size issue:

`ssize_t bytes_recd = recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof buf, 0);`
I was counting down the buffer size which I should not have been.

Comment: The file content indicates that you are downloading the whole web-page and not just the image. Have you looked into using CURL?

Comment: @Gaurav I want to do it using standard C libs, using sockets, first for learning at least. Then maybe I can move to something else. I want to know what I need to do to download the image, or any file.

Comment: I see! It's really a nice way to know the underlying mystery in the libraries. Nice approach. Even though you can refer the source of CURL to know how exactly it handles the specific request for downloading a file.

Comment: @Gaurav what makes you think it is a web page? (BTW: Do you mean HTML page?) For me it just looks like a HTTP header for an image file. A complete web page shouldn't contain "Content-Type: image/png"

Comment: `recv_all_to_file()` misses to return anything!

Answer (score 2):

Your response is the HTTP headers followed by the actual file contents. If you look at the headers, it says `Content-Length: 15467` which correctly matches with the file you are trying to download. So what you need to do is skip the headers and save the rest of the content in a file.

The headers are a bunch of text lines ending in `\r\n`. And the end of headers is signaled by `\r\n\r\n` (or an empty header).

What you need to do is keep reading from the socket till you see the first `\r\n\r\n` and store the stuff following it into a file (preferably with the extension `.png`).

I would also try to parse the `Content-Length` header since that gives you information on how many bytes you have to read after the headers have ended.

Now for why the output you get is actually less than the size of the file -

You have made a buffer of 3000 bytes, but you are requesting lesser and lesser amount of data. Infact after you have received 3000 bytes, you request nothing.
You need to fix you `recv` call as -

```
recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof buf, 0);
```

I tried your code and manually removed the headers from the saved file, renamed it as png and I can see the image.

Comment: Is this the general download approach for any type of file?

Comment: Yes, but some files also have for instance compression. In that case you need to uncompress the file. But you can request the server without any compression. The request headers you have sent tell the server that your client cannot support compression. In general for all files this technique should work.

Comment: "So, since you only request 3000 bytes, the rest is being discarded." I am using a stream socket so the rest should stay queued.

Comment: @sprocket12, yes I misread that. Have fixed the reasoning now.

Answer (score 2):

Ajay already explained the meaning of your received data. I will address the second part of your problem:

> Then lots of unknown content, but the file size is much smaller than it would be with the real image. What am I doing wrong?

If you add up the number of read bytes, you get 3000. Does that ring a bell?

```
while (1) { 
    ssize_t bytes_recd = recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof buf - total_bytes_recd, 0);
    ...
    total_bytes_recd += bytes_recd;
    fwrite(buf, bytes_recd, 1, file);
}
```

You limit your received bytes to the size of your buffer. That does not make any sense. Only for each read call this size is important. For total number of bytes you should not limit at all or take the value from the header (`"Content-Length: 15467"`) as maxmumum number.

Comment: aha, I modified the line and now the file is more like the real size.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your function for reading the response will only ever read up to 3,000 bytes, because each `recv` subtracts the bytes already read from the size of the buffer (3,000). You should just read the size of the buffer until the `recv` returns 0

```
while (1) { 
    ssize_t bytes_recd = recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof buf, 0);
    printf("\nReceived %d", bytes_recd);
    if (bytes_recd <= 0) {
        break;
    }
```

However, this will dump the entire stream into your file. What you *really* need to do is parse the `content-length` header to get the length of the body and then set `total_bytes_read` to that number plus what you have read up to and including the blank line separating the headers from the body.

In the general case, even that is not necessarily enough, because the web server is allowed to use chunked encoding which is a different way to signal how long the body is. At this point, it is better to give up and find an HTTP client library

Comment: Thanks, any HTTP client libs you recommend?

Comment: @sprocket12 [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) was already mentioned in the comments. It's a command line tool and a C library.